# What's wrong with this code for BST insertion?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So I wrote this code for Insertion of a node in BST (Binary Search Trees) but the program always prints that the tree is empty. I guess there's a problem with the function call I've made. Can you explain the problem.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;

    struct node
    {
        int key;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };


    void insert(node* root, int item)
    {
        if(root == NULL)
        {
            node* temp = new node();
            temp->key = item;
            temp->left = NULL;
            temp->right = NULL;
            root = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            if((root->key)>item)
            {
                insert(root->left,item);
            }
            else 
            {
                insert(root->right,item);
            }
        }
    }

    void inorder(node* root)
    {
        if(root!=NULL)
        {
            inorder(root->left);
            cout<<" "<<root->key<<" ";
            inorder(root->right);
        }
        else cout<<"The tree is empty.";
    }

    int main()
    {
        // cout<<endl<<" Here 5 ";
        node* root = NULL;
        int flag = 1 , item;
        while(flag == 1)
        {
            cout<<"Enter the number you want to enter : ";
            cin>>item;
            // cout<<endl<<" Here 6";
            insert(root, item);
            cout<<"Do you want to enter another number (1 -> YES)?";
            cin>>flag;
        }
        cout<<"The final tree is :";
        inorder(root);
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You have an uninitialized pointer in `node* root;`. It is not set to NULL unless you assign it that value.

Comment: I changed it to NULL. Still there is a problem that the ouput is always : "The tree is empty,"

Comment: The next problem is that you pass the `node` pointer by value to `insert`. That means that any changes to the pointer is local to that function, and does not affect the pointer in `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the insertion is slightly incorrect. The root pointer must be passed by reference. Just some such as:

```
void insert(node *& root, int item)
{
  if(root == NULL)
    {
      node* temp = new node();
      temp->key = item;
      temp->left = NULL;
      temp->right = NULL;
      root = temp;
    }
  else
    {
      if ((root->key) > item)
        {
          insert(root->left,item);
        }
      else 
        {
          insert(root->right,item);
        }
    }
}
```

which is structurally identic to your code (except for the reference to the root)

Also, your inorder traversal is bizarre because it will print out the message "The tree is empty." each time that the traversal detects a null node. I would modify thus:

```
void inorder(node* root)
{
  if (root == NULL)
    return;

  inorder(root->left);
  cout<<" "<<root->key<<" ";
  inorder(root->right);
}
```

Finally, I would slightly modify `main()` for managing the case when the tree is empty (instead of doing it inside inorder traversal):

```
int main()
{
  node* root = NULL;
  int flag = 1 , item;
  while(flag == 1)
    {
      cout<<"Enter the number you want to enter : ";
      cin>>item;
      insert(root, item);
      cout<<"Do you want to enter another number (1 -> YES)?";
      cin>>flag;
    }
  cout<<"The final tree is :";
  if (root == NULL)
    cout << "The tree is empty.";
  else
    inorder(root);
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```